# Why git difftool does not open vimdiff in case of conflicts?

Tags: git, vimdiff, git-difftool

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713765/viewing-all-git-diffs-with-vimdiff), 
I configured git to use vimdiff as diff/merge tool by adding following lines to my ~/.gitconfig:

```
[diff]
        tool = vimdiff
[merge]
        tool = vimdiff
[difftool]
        prompt = false
[alias]
        d = difftool
```

But `git difftool` still just prints diff (no vimdiff). Any ideas?

**UPDATE.**
Seems like `git difftool` works fine, if I have some uncommitted changes in repo, i.e. it opens vimdiff as expected. But it fails to open vimdiff if I do `git difftool` after merge with conflict. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741931/how-to-use-git-difftool-to-diff-merge-conflicts).
`git mergetool` must be used instead of `git difftool` in case of conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know as for the `why`.
But to fix it, reset the state of the conflicted file.

```
git status
    both modified: mymyfile.txt

git difftool myfile.txt #Fails
git reset myfile.txt

git status
    M myfile.txt

git difftool myfile.txt #should work
```